# JVM and Paging Memory

Tags: memory, jvm

I use windows 7 RAM usable 2.8 GB. I am able to allocate -Xmx1600 for JVM. beyond that JVM says could not allocate memory. I increased my Paging memory and the available paging  memory is more than 2 GB.RAM 2.8 and Paging 2 GB. Still i am able to allocate only -Xmx1600. Is paging memory not considerable for JVM???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using the 32 bit JVM.  In general the Java heap is bound by the amount of contiguous virtual address space available to the process.  In windows, this is typically between 1.6 & 1.7 GB, so is not unexpected.  See: [thanks for the memory](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-nativememory-linux/)

To go higher, use a 64 bit JVM.  Even better, use a 64 bit JVM with compressed references to minimize the footprint hit.  see: [usecompressedooops](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/CompressedOops)